# How do I display multiple cards of the data i fetched in vue?

Tags: css, vue.js

So i have  my beers component and beer detaillist component in de second one i used a card with bootstrap to display image title etc. My problem is that i want to display the cards in multiple rows and column. i have tried a few ways but failed so can some one tell me how to go about it?

beers

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-bind:key="beer.id" v-for="beer in beers">
      <BeerDetailsList v-bind:beer="beer" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import BeerDetailsList from "./BeerDetailsList";
export default {
  components: { BeerDetailsList },
  name: "Beers",
  props: ["beers"],
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

beer details list

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <b-card-group deck>
      <b-card
        :title="beer.name"
        :img-src="beer.image_url"
        :alt="beer.name"
        img-top
        tag="article"
        style="max-width: 20rem ;"
        class="mb-2"
      >
        <b-card-text>
          {{ beer.tagline }}
        </b-card-text>

        <b-button href="#" variant="primary">View Beer details</b-button>
      </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "BeerDetailsList",
  props: ["beer"],
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your for loop on the `b-card-group` component to at first specify the rows with at most 4 cards.
Then you have to put another for loop on the `b-card` component to print 4 cards for each card group.

You do not need any second component. eg code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
        <b-card-group deck v-for="i in Math.ceil(beers.length/4)" :key="i">
          <b-card
            v-bind:key="beer.id"
            v-for="beer in beers.slice((i-1)*4, (i-1)*4 +  4)"
            :title="beer.name"
            :img-src="beer.image_url"
            :alt="beer.name"
            img-top
            style="max-width: 20rem ;"
            class="mb-2"
          >
            <b-card-text>
              {{ beer.tagline }}
            </b-card-text>
            <b-button href="#" variant="primary">View Beer details</b-button>
            
          </b-card>
        </b-card-group>
      </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Beers",
  props: ["beers"],
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: apart from that i still just get one colum of the card, my question is how do i get for example 4 collums in 4 row s of these cards

Comment: I have updated the code. It should now show 4 cards in each row @lydiamichael

Comment: thank you, i've tried it but i only get a black screen

Comment: Sorry, there was a console error in my previous code. I have fixed it. Check ot now @lydiamichael